# meteor 1.3 not recognized on the command line

Tags: meteor

Re:  How to Update to Meteor 1.3;

Previously meteor 1.2 was working on windows 10 - after update 'meteor' was not recognized from the command line. 
 My system environmental variables are set to C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local.meteor
Has anybody installed 'meteor 1.3 on
Windows 10? What environmental variables path is working?
Thanks - Phil

Comment: If you fixed the problem, _write an answer_. Don't vandalise the question. And clean up the question as it's really hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 0):

Re: My Update to Meteor 1.3 has worked
 1) uninstalled meteor
 2) Freed up memory on windows system       3) unzipped Github meteor to C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local.meteor 4)Set environmental variables path to match 
5)from a 1.2 meteor app file ran meteor update from admin command line result: release 1.3.1
-Phil